# Recursive regex and group searching in PCRE

Tags: php, regex, recursion, pcre

I have a routing system in this form: `website/(:option)(:option)(:option(:option))` or
`website/archive(/:year(/:month(-:day))) (/page/:page)`. The `( )` represents an optional path and `:string` represents a variable that will be replaced. In case of nested parentheses, I need all variables to continue (there may be an *unlimited* number of parentheses).

I’m using PCRE in PHP. I need to select all the `(:string)`, so I thought about this regex : `\([^\(\)]*:[^\(\)]+\)`. I experience problems with recursive and group regex searching.

Example: `website/archive(/2015(/:month(:day)))` will select `(/:month(:day))`
Example: `website/archive(/:year(/03(27)))` will select `(/:year(/03(27)))`

[Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/3ams1)

Can someone explain to me how the recursion works and if it’s even possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>try this pattern</s>

```
(\((?:[^()]|(?R))*\))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/240)

---

after reading comment below, use this pattern, check against sub-pattern #1

```
\(([^():\r\n]*:[^()]+(\((?:[^()]|(?2))*\))\))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/242)
you may remove `\r\n` if it is not a multi-line input

Comment: And where's the answer to the *"Can someone explain to me how the recursion works"* question? Recursion is trickier than average, some kind of explanation could be nice instead of just posting a raw pattern. BTW you can optimize that with `\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)`

Comment: The problem with this pattern, he's also capturing string in this form `(string)` that doesn’t contain a `:` character. 

An example with : `website/archive(/2015(/:month(:day)))` : the year is set, so doesn't need to capture it, but `month` isn’t set, so the capture will be `(/:month(:day))`
The same way goes if `day` is set but not `year`: `website/archive(/:year(/:month(27)))` so the capture will stay be `(/:year(/:month(27)))`.
It's like nested IF conditions, if the first isn’t satisfied the next can't be reached.

Comment: @Fox, Updated my answer above!

Comment: There are still pattern the regex don't select : [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZ4oJ6/1)
But for now he does what I wanted. So the question has been resolved. Thanks!